# Trouble with changing text on a textbox in vb

Tags: .net, vb.net

Hello I am having a problem changing the text color of a textbox in vb I know that changing is like this

Textbox.ForeColor = Color.Red

when I do this it doesn't change anything still gives me the same black color . Also can it be because it in read only or is there some wrong with visual studio or My project

Edit: I am using VB 9 or VB 2008 w/ VS 2008 Express

Comment: vb6? vb.net? I tried it using VBA and it seems to be working. Not sure, why that should not work in vb6/vb.net?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately I don't think you can easily change the colours on a read-only textbox. There are [some](http://www.pcreview.co.uk/forums/thread-1297661.php) [workarounds](http://www.syncfusion.com/FAQ/windowsforms/faq_c94c.aspx#q866q) but they're a bit hacky.

Comment: Jon: Could this be a bug? I mean, in VB6 and other form based frameworks prior to .net - the expectation was met & it is not the case with .net framework. Your thoughts?

Comment: Are you absolutely *sure* that it works with VB6? As I understood it, this is an issue with the Win32 textbox control. I haven't done any Win32 work for a long time though...

Answer (score 1):

It will work if you change the color and then reassign the text.

```
dim s as string
s = TextBox1.Text
TextBox1.ForeColor = Color.AliceBlue
TextBox1.Text = s
```

Answer (score 0):

Go to propeties of text box find something called back color and you can change the color